# Error ggplotly: VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'NULL'

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm using `R 3.3.3` and RStudio `1.0.136`, and the latest versions of all the packages.

I get this error with the `plotly` package

```
> ggiris <- qplot(Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, data = iris, color = Species)
> ggplotly(ggiris)
Error in grid.Call(L_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'NULL'
```

This error does not occur anymore after I "print" the ggplot:

```
> ggiris
> ggplotly(ggiris)
```

It occurs not only in RStudio, but also in a Shiny app.

Any hint ?

**Note:** This more likely occurs with a "fresh" session (just after opening RStudio).

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Belgium.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=French_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.5.6  ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9       tidyr_0.6.1       viridisLite_0.1.3 digest_0.6.12    
 [5] dplyr_0.5.0       assertthat_0.1    grid_3.3.3        plyr_1.8.4       
 [9] R6_2.2.0          jsonlite_1.3      gtable_0.2.0      DBI_0.6          
[13] magrittr_1.5      scales_0.4.1      httr_1.2.1        lazyeval_0.2.0   
[17] labeling_0.3      tools_3.3.3       htmlwidgets_0.8   purrr_0.2.2      
[21] munsell_0.4.3     yaml_2.1.14       base64enc_0.1-3   colorspace_1.3-2 
[25] htmltools_0.3.5   tibble_1.2
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with: `R version 3.3.2
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
...
other ... :
[1] plotly_4.5.6   ggplot2_2.2.1
loaded ... :
[1] Rcpp_0.12.9   tidyr_0.6.1   viridisLite_0.1.3 digest_0.6.12   dplyr_0.5.0   assertthat_0.1   grid_3.3.2   
plyr_1.8.4   R6_2.2.0   jsonlite_1.2   gtable_0.2.0   DBI_0.5-1   magrittr_1.5   scales_0.4.1   
httr_1.2.1   lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3   tools_3.3.2   htmlwidgets_0.8   purrr_0.2.2   munsell_0.4.3   
yaml_2.1.14   base64enc_0.1-3   colorspace_1.3-2   htmltools_0.3.5   tibble_1.2`

Comment: Thank you for testing @apom. Me too, I've never encountered this issue on 3.3.2.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it either, R 3.3.2 and R 3.3.3 using RStudio 1.0.136 on Windows 10

Comment: This occurs for me too. `RStudio 1.0.136, R 3.3.3, Windows 7 x64, ggplot2_2.2.1` Seems quite random. I restart my session to get rid of it. I am only using ggplot2. So, this probably not a ggplotly issue.

Comment: Thanks @rmf, I'm feeling less alone now. As you say, quite random.

Comment: I got the same error in R version 3.2.3 (Ubuntu command-line). I am using pheatmap. Started a new session and no error.

Comment: This https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2919 suggests that the problem may come from having a NULL Viewport, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Attempting to set a viewport from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/viewports.pdf fails.
~~~
> fullheight <- convertHeight(sum(tg$heights),"in",valueOnly = TRUE)
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'NULL'

> .Call(grid:::C_gridDirty)
    NULL

> .Call(grid:::C_currentViewport)
    NULL

> vptst <- viewport()
> pushViewport(vptst)
    Error in grid.Call(C_setDLelt, x) : 
      INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'NULL'
~~~

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same error when I change characteristics associated with a ggplotly object within a package I am building.  Short term fix is to quit and restart the session, as mentioned in a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error on my computer, for the same context. I simply update packages from RStudio interface, then I get the error. You probably need to update your R version, it worked for me.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: This error "randomly" occurs for me. I have all the latest versions, of the packages and R.

Comment: Have you found a solution @StéphaneLaurent? I have the same error on a script that runs every weekday and the error occurs about once a month. On scheduled scripts its not possible for me to restart R/Rstudio or other quick fixes. Would be very thankful for any hints,...